# How can I get the floating-point square root using only binary operations?

Tags: floating-point, bitwise-operators

I am trying to get the floating-point square root in binary representation. I found the Newton's method, but it deals with decimal representation. Is there an algorithm to do it in binary representation?

In other words, only using bitwise operations.

Comment: Newton's method operates on abstract quantities, not specific representations.  Please edit your question to show us what you've tried.  Right now your question doesn't reveal any understanding of the problem and doesn't explain your requirements in sufficient detail.

Comment: You can find solution in wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method

Comment: Numbers mean the same thing regardless of what representation you use. Newton's method works fine in binary, octal, decimal, hexadecimal, and any other representation you can think of. I suspect you want to know how to compute square roots using only operations like bit shifting, bitwise or, bitwise and, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PDF at [Zuse's Z3 Square Root Algorithm](http://www4.wittenberg.edu/academics/mathcomp/bjsdir/ZuseZ3Talk.pdf) explains the algorithm used by the Z3 machine from 1939 to do square roots of floating point numbers using only binary operations.

The square root algorithm used by the Z3 was the binary analog of the "[completing the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square)" algorithm, a manual technique for obtaining a square root one digit at a time.

The algorithm is in page 5

From the summary "...3. A close examination of this algorithm reveals that it requires only the operations of subtraction, left shift (multiplication by 2) , set bit, and test if positive or zero. - all of which are easy to implement in binary logic."